# Conditionally separate array keys and values into separate arrays

Tags: php

Actually, I don't like to write `for`/`foreach`.

I had to write a loop. I would like to replace it with `array_map`/`array_walk`.

The code:

```
foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
    if(isset(static::$specialKeywords[$value])) {
        unset($data[$key]);
        $check['specialKeys'][] = $key;
        $check['specialValues'][] = $value;
        continue;
    }
    $check['keys'][] = $key;
    $check['values'][] = $value;
}
```

Comment: "This code block" — what does it do? Please explain, and also make it your question title. See [ask].

Comment: it does not look like a mapping its more like a filtering. also, do you store all your "special keywords" as an array key? if not, `isset(static::$specialKeywords[$value])` won't help you to find an element in an array.

Comment: As we all want to make our code more efficient or improve it in one way or another, try to write a title that summarizes what your code does, not what you want to get out of a review.

Comment: @Jamal what does this question need to qualify for reopening?  If it is irreparably broken, should it be deleted?

Comment: @mickmackusa It's because it looked more like example code, with the poorly descriptive title and variable names.  Other than that, it's probably not best for deletion as it already has upvoted answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mapping is basically walking on an element set (array) and manipulating it. Your case is a filtering. I would prefer using `foreach` since it's more readable, but if you don't want to use `foreach` try using array functions then.  Find the intersect stack then get a diff to generate your clean array.  And just getting keys and values to generate the ultimate array you want.

```
<?php

$special_items = array_intersect($data, $specialKeywords);
$others = array_diff($data,$special_items);
$check['keys'] = array_keys($others);
$check['values'] = array_values($others);
$check['specialKeys'] = array_keys($special_items);
$check['specialValues'] = array_values($special_items);
//$others is your new $data since you want to unset all items contain special keywords
```

Comment: According to the original piece of code it has to be ```array_intersect($data, array_keys($specialKeywords));```

Comment: right, asked that to question owner to make sure he really is storing special keywords as keys. I will update the answer once he clarify.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, you should use `array_filter`. `array_map` and `array_walk` would apply a method to every member of the array but would not be able to remove elements from the returning array. By the way, this method is a good example for what not to do in functional programming. `unset` is all about side effects.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've provided

```
function sort ($value, $key, &$check) {
    if (isset(static::$specialKeywords[$value])) {
        $check['specialKeys'][] = $key;
        $check['specialValues'][] = $value;
    }
    else {
        $check['keys'][] = $key;
        $check['values'][] = $value;
    }
}
array_walk($data, sort, $check);
```

1. Extract the logic inside your `foreach` and place it in a separate function
2. Use `array_walk`to populate the desired arrays

Now I'm no PHP expert, but that's how I'd do it based on the [official documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php).

I do have to agree that `unset` is a recipe for disaster. If you really want to save memory, maybe use `unset($data)`to remove the original array once you're done.

It appears that `array_walk` cannot pass the 3rd parameter by reference, thus invalidating the code above. Please see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5155411/pass-by-reference-the-third-parameter-in-php-array-walk-without-a-warning) for a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I like the solution proposed by @Tufan Barış Yıldırım.

In case you avoid loops to have a declarative code without intermediate states, you can use [partition](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl#partitionpredicate-sequence) function from [Nspl](https://github.com/ihor/Nspl).

```
use function \nspl\a\partition;

// ... 

$isSpecial = function($value) {
    return isset(static::$specialKeywords[$value]);
};

list($special, $data) = partition($isSpecial, $data);

// ...
```

Now  `$special` contains special values and `$data` contains only non-special values. I don't know how to fill `$check` array nicely. You can use the same approach as in @Tufan Barış Yıldırım answer.